# Where should I install the zsh completion file as a package maintainer

Tags: linux, zsh

I have a project that contains a completion script for zsh, where should I copy the completion file to when the user install the software (such as by running `make install`, `apt install` or `pacman -Si`...)?

I know there's some specific directory for completion script for other shell such as:
**fish** -> `/usr/share/fish/vendor_completions.d`
**bash** -> `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`

what about zsh?
**zsh** -> `/usr/share/???`

Comment: Correction 2022: packages should install bash completions to `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions`. `/etc/bash_completion.d` is long deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: I've removed the `/etc/bash_completion.d` to avoid providing outdated information.

Answer (score 7):

The paths `zsh` uses for completion functions are configurable (see [`${fpath[@]}`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Use-of-compinit)), but it’s safe to follow [systemd’s example](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/shell-completion/zsh/meson.build): install them in `share/zsh/site-functions` under the installation prefix by default, but allow that to be overridden. The installation prefix should be `/usr/local` by default.

For packaged completions, Fedora and derivatives use `/usr/share/zsh/site-functions`, Debian and derivatives use `/usr/share/zsh/vendor-completions`; you shouldn’t care about the particular directories used here, but this situation explains why it’s useful to allow the completion installation directory to be overridden.

For non-packaged completions, both distributions support `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`.

Answer (score 2):

[Since zsh 5.0.7](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html), the default function load path (`$fpath`) includes `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`. So install your completion functions there.

Note that `/usr/share/fish/vendor_completions.d` and `/usr/share/fish/vendor_completions.d` are wrong. Running `make install` should not add or modify anything under `/usr/bin`, `/usr/lib`, `/usr/share` or any other part of `/usr` that isn't `/usr/local` (unless explicitly directed). `/usr` is reserved for files installed by a distribution. Things installed manually, for example via `make install`, go under [`/usr/local`](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html#usrlocalLocalHierarchy).